# While uploading large video from work manager, app is crashed suddenly in some devices

Tags: android, out-of-memory, retrofit, android-workmanager

Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Failed to allocate a 165377344 byte allocation with 8507672 free bytes and 8308KB until OOM, target footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912

Comment: You're trying to allocate 165MB of memory at once. You'll need to rework your entire approach if that's ever something that is possible.

Comment: maybe you're leaking memory. use leakcanary to find out what's causing the issue.

Comment: how can i upload large video